# PGF plot: How to draw two bars next to each other for the same x label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw a min,max,avg plot. Now I want to draw a two bars next to each other for the same x value. Right now I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0] 
\begin{axis} [
    width  = 0.32*\textwidth,
    height = 6cm,
    symbolic x coords={L1, L2, L1+SSIM},
    xtick=data,
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
    use comma,
    1000 sep={},
    title style={yshift=1.5ex, font=\bfseries},
    title={}
]
\addplot+[black, very thick, forget plot,only marks] 
  plot[very thick, error bars/.cd, y dir=plus, y explicit]
  table[x=x,y=mean_mae,y error expr=\thisrow{best_mae}] {\mytable};
\addplot+[black, very thick, only marks,xticklabels=\empty] 
  plot[very thick, error bars/.cd, y dir=plus, y explicit]
  table[x=x,y=mean_mae,y error expr=\thisrow{worst_mae}] {\mytable};
 \addplot+[blue, very thick, forget plot,only marks] 
  plot[very thick, error bars/.cd, y dir=plus, y explicit]
  table[x=x,y=mean_mae,y error expr=\thisrow{best_mae}] {\mytable};
\addplot+[blue, very thick, only marks,xticklabels=\empty, xshift=1mm] 
  plot[very thick, error bars/.cd, y dir=plus, y explicit]
  table[x=x,y=mean_mae,y error expr=\thisrow{worst_mae}] {\mytable};

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with this picture as reslut:

[image]

But as you can see it draws the blue line over the black one. But I want to have it next to each other. Is there something like a shift I can add to \addplot ?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. You are already using `xshift` - Is that not what you are asking for?